# Why there is no resources represented on DBpedia-Live after 2016?

Tags: dbpedia

I have noticed that in Wikipedia, new ressources and updates after 2016 aren't represented in DBpedia-Live (like movies released after 2016), isn't DBpedia-Live supposed to be a much current version than DBpedia? for example, the movie "Spiderman: far from home" isn't represented, why so?

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaken, but I don't know how you came to be so, because you provided no information about how you reached your conclusion.

- Wikipedia article -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home
- DBpedia-Live (definitely exists) -- http://live.dbpedia.org/resource/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home
- DBpedia (doesn't exist) -- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home

Comment: I wanna know which query did you used in http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql to find the description in DBpedia-Live please, and  why the type of this entity (Spider-Man: Far From Home) is a "Thing" and not a "Film" ?

Comment: @MohamedAmineFerradji - (1) You mentioned a specific entity that you couldn't find in DBpedia-Live which I found immediately. What query did you try? That would help us guide you to improving it.

Comment: (2) Something disrupted the DBpedia-Live ingestion process, so its content is about a month behind Wikipedia at the moment. That disruption has been addressed, and [DBpedia-Live is catching up now](http://live.dbpedia.org/live/).

Comment: (3/3) This film's page was ingested on August 2; a great many changes have been made to it since then, and should be ingested today. This may also resolve the apparent `rdf:type` error in the DBpedia-Live data. If not, I encourage you to post to the [DBpedia Forum](https://forum.dbpedia.org) or the [DBpedia Discussion mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dbpedia/lists/dbpedia-discussion).

Comment: I used this query : SELECT *
WHERE {
?x rdfs:label "Spider-Man: Far From Home"@en .
} but it gave me this http://dbpedia.org/page/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home , not the DBpedia-live version and for the rdf : type thing, I noticed that the movies representation in DBpedia with the type: Film have more properties than their representation in DBpedia-live with the type: Thing, I'd like to know if there is a DBpedia-live representation for spiderman: far from home with the type: Film because I need the property dbo:gross

Comment: `<http://dbpedia.org/page/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home>` is a page that describes the entity identified by `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home>`. `<http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home>` describes the same entity. Also, `{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home> owl:sameAs <http://live.dbpedia.org/resource/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home> }`.

Comment: As to `dbo:gross` on DBpedia Live, you should post to the DBpedia Forum, as suggested previously. I suggest you point out the differences between <http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_(2012_film)> and <http://live.dbpedia.org/page/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_(2012_film)>.

Comment: which query did you use on DBpedia-live sparql endpoint to get this version <http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home> ?

Comment: I just added `live.` to the URI for the DBpedia Snapshot page, to get the DBpedia Live page. (Worth noting, DBpedia Live is now up to August 24 on the Wikipedia change-log backlog, and continues applying updates to roughly 4000 entities per minute.)